# Blow it off vs blow off

Tags: grammar

The soup was hot.

> "Blow it off."
>
> "Blow it."

I told him to blow the soup himself.

Do I need to add "off" after that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This US English speaker would say **"Blow *on* it."**

The reason for this is that when we say "Blow it" the object of the verb is the thing you are actually blowing with your mouth: for example, you would [*blow the trumpet*](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1234&bih=755&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=blow%20the%20trumpet&oq=blow%20the%20trumpet&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67k1j0j0i8i30k1l2j0i24k1l6.2195.2195.0.2816.1.1.0.0.0.0.90.90.1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.90....0.maNOpvHb_oU) to play it, or [*blow a bubble* with bubble gum or soap bubbles](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1234&bih=755&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=blow%20a%20bubble&oq=blow%20a%20bubble&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l2j0i30k1j0i5i30k1l7.38115.39551.0.39679.8.8.0.0.0.0.106.659.7j1.8.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.8.658...0i24k1.0.bHU3tj6uqMc), but you are not doing either of those things with the soup.

"Blow it off" is a little better but still not what we would say, idiomatically.  Partly, this is because [*blow it off* idiomatically means "decide to ignore it"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/blow-it-off).

Comment: British English too, especially as "blow off" is a euphemism for "fart".